# Tag dataframe origin of rows after merge

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I need to merge in order to compare the differences between two methods. What I need to do is to track which dataframe to rows in the resulting dataframe come from. I thus want to create a column carrying tht information in some way, either by tagging `left`, `right`, `left+rihgt` or any other way.

So, as an example, comsider the following:

```
Left =
   A  B
0  a  2
1  b  3
2  c  5
3  d  5
```

and

```
Right = 
   A  R
0  a  3
1  b  4
2  e  7
3  f  5
```

which I merge

```
Both = Left.merge(Right,right_on ="A", left_on="A", how ="outer")
```

resulting in

```
   A    B    R
0  a  2.0  3.0
1  b  3.0  4.0
2  c  5.0  NaN
3  d  5.0  NaN
4  e  NaN  7.0
5  f  NaN  5.0
```

Now, in this elementary example, it is evident which row come from which df, but it might not always be that easy. Furthermore, I do not want to manually append the origin information. What I need is

```
   A    B    R  Origin
0  a  2.0  3.0  left+right
1  b  3.0  4.0  left+right
2  c  5.0  NaN  left
3  d  5.0  NaN  left
4  e  NaN  7.0  right
5  f  NaN  5.0  right
```

I know that using conditions and choices works, but I was hoping for something more compact.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `indicator=True`, then rename column and replace values if necessary:

```
d = {'Origin':{'both':'left+right','left_only':'left','right_only':'right'}}
Both = (Left.merge(Right,on ="A",  how ="outer", indicator=True)
            .rename(columns={'_merge':'Origin'})
            .replace(d))
print (Both)
   A    B    R      Origin
0  a  2.0  3.0  left+right
1  b  3.0  4.0  left+right
2  c  5.0  NaN        left
3  d  5.0  NaN        left
4  e  NaN  7.0       right
5  f  NaN  5.0       right
```